# Ionic hiding elements until scroll event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am conditionally showing and hiding elements in my app in an accordion like fashion (can be seen in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGgmRtJI1nA&feature=youtu.be)).

The code to perform this is:

```
   <div class="filter-menu" ng-repeat="group in Filters | orderBy: 'title'">
        <div class="filter-menu-titles" ng-click="toggleGroup(group)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
            <i class="icon energized" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? '{{group.icon}}-active' : '{{group.icon}}'"></i> &nbsp; <span class="filter-title-text" ng-class="{orange: isGroupShown(group)}"> {{group.title}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ion-checkbox-viewport">
            <span class="filter-header" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">{{group.title}}</span>
            <br />
            <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="filter in group.filters | orderBy: 'name'" class="item-accordion" value="{{filter.name}}" ng-model="filter.checked" ng-change="ModifyFilter(filter)" ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
                {{filter.name}}
            </ion-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {

    if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
        $scope.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
        $scope.shownGroup = group;
    }
};

$scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
};
```

This works perfectly on the first load of the view. However when I navigate away from the view and then come back the elements that are shown and hidden conditionally are all hidden until a scroll event is performed. When scrolling occurs the elements are shown again.

This only occurs on iOS.

Comment: Seems like rendering issue,may be try out template force refresh at start of controller `$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});`

Comment: Hmmm, i wouldn't be keen on this because I load data from the server on navigating to the new. Additionally that code causes a crash.

Comment: ahan, try `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`. Plus instead of variable use object `$scope.activeGroup = {group: set-group-value}`. Simple variables does not get updated in scope sometimes.

Comment: hmmm, i'm not you what you mean by `$scope.activeGroup = {group: set-group-value}` where am I replacing with this?

Comment: I fixed this by re-positioning my HTML - there must have been an issue with the layering of the views.